# \nocite{*} for single bibdatasources with biblatex/biber

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

Several bibliography resources are used in one single tex-document.
They resources have been added using: `\addbibresource{}`.
Now I'd like to use the `\nocite{*}` command to print all references of
one of the bibresources. However `\nocite{*}` does consider all resources instead
of just a single source (in the case of the example it should be resource2). Is there a way
to specify that with `\nocite{*}`?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-resource1.bib}
@article{A2014,
author={First Author},
journal={Journal A},
title={First Paper},
year={2014}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-resource2.bib}
@article{B2014,
author={Another Author},
journal={Journal B},
title={Second Paper},
year={2014}
}
@article{C2014,
author={Next Author},
journal={Journal C},
title={Third Paper},
year={2014}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}         


%bib
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex} % load the package
\addbibresource{\jobname-resource1.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-resource2.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

This is a citation \cite{C2014}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is using `\nocite{key}` an option for you? (Probably not)

Comment: \nocite{key} is the last option (would be quite some manual work, to add and check references)

Comment: Well, it is no problem to get `biblatex` to distinguish the two bibliography sources (via `keywords` or the like), but it seems to be quite hard to make `biblatex` `\nocite` a lot of entries but not all.

Comment: One problem for `biblatex` is that it is only able to see the entries once they are in the `.bbl` file, but in order for an entry to get into the `.bbl` file it will have to be `\cite`d or `\nocite`d.

Comment: Since I feel that really none of the solutions is the ne plus ultra answer, I have filed a bug report [#228 on the `biblatex` bugtracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/228).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can do this quite easily using reference sections with bound datasources:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{resource1.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}[resource2.bib]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here, the first `\nocite` only adds the references from `resource2.bib` because it's local to the refsection. The second `\nocite` only picks up things from `resource1.bib` because both are in refsection "'0". `\printbibliography` is local to a refsection if it has no `section` argument.

Here's another way of thinking about this and why it's hard in general. `biblatex` works semantically with bibliographies and so the way to cite things is by semantic information that applies to bibliographies - citekeys, entry types, reference sections etc. `biber` knows how to map these to things to a semantically lower level like files, tags in an XML file (the `.bcf`) and the like. The problem is that what is wanted is a `biblatex` way of specifying cite keys at a semantic level below that of "bibliography" e.g. "file". `biblatex` has no concept of such things in its code and it's very hard to implement (and would be very messy). It can pass through such foreign concepts like *file names* to `biber` but that's not enough for this case as `biblatex` internal data structures would need to track citation and sorting lists at the "file" semantic level and that's impossible. Simply put, there would need to be a bibliographic semantic component between "one or more citation keys" and "all citation keys in a refsection" which is all `\nocite` currently understands. "File" is already ruled out for reasons mentioned above.

Comment: But is there a solution to print the local bibliographies for `refsection` 0 *and* 1 in one `\printbibliography` command? (I think that is specifically what the OP was after). Just printing `\printbibliography[section=0]` and `\printbibliograohy[section=1]` one after the other (and maybe suppressing spacing and headings along the way) will seriously mess up sorting.

Comment: Hmm, that's basically impossible as a refsection is such a fundamental unit in biber. Sorting, disambiguation etc. is always calculated within a refsection.

Comment: this answer saved my day! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

The following approach is not entirely satisfying because technically for `biblatex` all entries will have been `\`(`no`)`cite`d, this leads to `biblatex` applying disambiguation techniques it would not have to use.

The main idea is to use a sourcemap restricted to `\jobname-resource2.bib`

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-resource2.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={, nocitethis}, append]
    }
  }
}
```

to add a keyword `nocitethis` to all the entries in that file.

We also define `\bibcheck`

```
\defbibcheck{mynocite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifciteseen} or test {\ifkeyword{nocitethis}}}
    {}
    {\skipentry}
}
```

This check will only print entries in the bibliography that either were cited before or have the specific keyword `nocitethis` that only entries from `\jobname-resource2.bib` have.

It remains to issue a `\nocite{*}` (so technically all entries are `\nocited` and processed by biber).

You will have to use the `bibcheck` in the bibliography

```
\printbibliography[check=mynocite]
```

We also will need to load `biblatex` with `citetracker` enabled in order for `\ifciteseen` to work

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,citetracker=true]{biblatex}
```

MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-resource1.bib}
@article{A2014,
author={First Author},
journal={Journal A},
title={First Paper},
note = {should appear in bib, because it was cited},
year={2014}
}
@article{D2014,
author={First Author},
journal={Journal A},
title={First Paper},
note = {should not be seen in bib},
year={2014}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-resource2.bib}
@article{B2014,
author={Another Author},
journal={Journal B},
title={Second Paper},
note = {should appear in bib, b/c it is in \jobname-resource2 and nocite was issued},
year={2014}
}
@article{C2014,
author={Next Author},
journal={Journal C},
title={Third Paper},
note = {should appear in bib, b/c it is in \jobname-resource2 and nocite was issued},
year={2014}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}         

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,citetracker=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname-resource1.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-resource2.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-resource2.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={, nocitethis}, append]
    }
  }
}

\defbibcheck{mynocite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifciteseen} or test {\ifkeyword{nocitethis}}}
    {}
    {\skipentry}
}

\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
  This is a citation \cite{A2014}

  \printbibliography[check=mynocite]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You will notice that there is a "(2014a)" but no "(2014b)", for Biber "(2014b)" exists - it is `D2014` - and has been cited (because of `\nocite{*}`), we just suppress it in the bibliography via our check.

Comment: Maybe the feature to apply `\nocite` to only a particular bib source is worth a feature request in the [`biblatex` bugtracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/). Also just another thought: Maybe one could cook something up with `refsections`, this might not work for one bibliography though.

Comment: The problem with disambiguation can be dealt with by adding the "dataonly" option to the `options` field for the entries you don't want considered for this (using `DeclareSourcemap`).

Comment: @moewe I think the difficulty is with `biber` and not `biblatex` since all `biber` see of `nocite{*}` is `<bcf:citekey order="0">*</bcf:citekey>`. I don't know enough about `biber` to know if it can handle additional options with a `*` cite.

Comment: @StrongBad Indeed it is Biber that applies the techniques, I maybe should have been clearer on that in the post.

Comment: @PLK I did not think of that, but is it possible to add `dataonly` to only those entries with true `\citeseen`? Adding that keyword to all entries of a file will not yield the expected results.

Comment: My point was that the feature request probably should be aimed at `biber` and not `biblatex`.

Comment: @StrongBad Ahhh, OK. I automatically refer people to the `biblatex` bugtracker, but I think this would have to be implemented in `biblatex` as well as Biber.

Answer (score 6):

I second the suggestion that being able to 'nocite' all entries in a specific `.bib` file would be useful, but until that happens, it is not tricky to quickly grab those citations all in one go.

Imagine we want to populate a single file with all entry keys from a `.bib` file, so we can simply add a

```
\input{nocites}
```

That means we need a file called `nocites.tex` that has something like

```
% nocites.tex
\nocite{%
 entrykey1, entrykey2, entrykey3, entrykey4, % ...
}
```

Using `grep`, `sed`, and `tr`, we can do this easily (and people better with regex will probably do it even more easily/efficiently):

```sh
# assuming a .bib file called `bibliography.bib`
grep @ bibliography.bib | grep -v '@string' | grep -v '\\\@' | sed 's/@.*{//g' | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/^/\\nocite{%\n/' | sed '$a}' > nocites.tex
```

What this does is:

1. find each line that has an '@' in it;
2. discard any line that has a '@string' in it (optional);
3. discard any line that has a '\@' in it (optional; my `.bib` file would need this);
4. remove from each matching line the `@<entrytype>{` (e.g., turn `@Book{entry1` into `entry1`);
5. turn all new lines into a single line separated by spaces (optional);
6. prepend to the file a `\nocite{%` while moving the entry keys to the next line;
7. append a closing `}` to the end of the file;
8. write all these transformations to a file called `nocites.tex`.

Comment: Nice. I suggest to put `grep "^@"` instead. It was needed in my case since I had many lines with `@` (in the abstracts).

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to achieve because of `biber`. When you do `\nocite{*}` this causes

```
<bcf:citekey order="0">*</bcf:citekey>
```

to be written to the `bcf` file which is read by `biber` and then used to create the `bbl` file which is used by `biblatex`. Without modifying `biber`, we are forced to get `biblatex` to write something in the `bcf` file that will cause `biber` to write something to the `bbl` file that can be modify with TeX.

```
...
\addbibresource{\jobname-resource2.bib}
\begin{document}
This is a citation \cite{C2014}
\begin{refsection}[\jobname-resource1.bib]
\nocite{*}
\end{refsection}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

results in

```
...
\refsection{0}
  \sortlist{entry}{nyt}
    \entry{C2014}{article}{}
      \name{labelname}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=4a521548b416f55cd43a36d33ade6d23}{Author}{A\bibinitperiod}{Next}{N\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=4a521548b416f55cd43a36d33ade6d23}{Author}{A\bibinitperiod}{Next}{N\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{4a521548b416f55cd43a36d33ade6d23}
      \strng{fullhash}{4a521548b416f55cd43a36d33ade6d23}
      \field{sortinit}{A}
      \field{labelyear}{2014}
      \field{datelabelsource}{}
      \field{labeltitle}{Third Paper}
      \field{journaltitle}{Journal C}
      \field{title}{Third Paper}
      \field{year}{2014}
    \endentry
  \endsortlist
\endrefsection

\refsection{1}
  \sortlist{entry}{nyt}
    \entry{A2014}{article}{}
      \name{labelname}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=5ce4601588022c38e60ef07ac0267cd5}{Author}{A\bibinitperiod}{First}{F\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=5ce4601588022c38e60ef07ac0267cd5}{Author}{A\bibinitperiod}{First}{F\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{5ce4601588022c38e60ef07ac0267cd5}
      \strng{fullhash}{5ce4601588022c38e60ef07ac0267cd5}
      \field{sortinit}{A}
      \field{labelyear}{2014}
      \field{datelabelsource}{}
      \field{labeltitle}{First Paper}
      \field{journaltitle}{Journal A}
      \field{title}{First Paper}
      \field{year}{2014}
    \endentry
  \endsortlist
\endrefsection
\endinput
```

being written to the `bbl`. If we then hack the `\refsection`, `\endsortlist`, `\endrefsection`, and `\sortlist` macros at the right time we can get the desired output. Specifically we need

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\def\blx@bblfile@biber{%
  \blx@secinit
  \begingroup


  \blx@bblstart
  \blx@ifsigned{\jobname}{bbl}
    {%
\LetLtxMacro{\refsectionOld}{\refsection}
\LetLtxMacro{\endsortlistOld}{\endsortlist}
\LetLtxMacro{\endrefsectionOld}{\endrefsection}
\LetLtxMacro{\sortlistOld}{\sortlist}
\def\refsection{\def\refsection{\@gobble}\refsectionOld}
\def\endsortlist{\def\endsortlist{\endsortlistOld}}
\def\endrefsection{\def\endrefsection{\endrefsectionOld}}
\def\sortlist{\def\sortlist{\@gobbletwo}\sortlistOld}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.bbl}
       {\blx@info@noline{... file '\jobname.bbl' found}}
       {\blx@info@noline{... file '\jobname.bbl' not found}%
        \typeout{No file \jobname.bbl.}}}
    {}%
  \blx@bblend
  \endgroup
  \csnumgdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}}

\makeatother
```

Putting it altogether into a MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-resource1.bib}
@article{A2014,
author={First Author},
journal={Journal A},
title={First Paper},
year={2014}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-resource2.bib}
@article{B2014,
author={Another Author},
journal={Journal B},
title={Second Paper},
year={2014}
}
@article{C2014,
author={Next Author},
journal={Journal C},
title={Third Paper},
year={2014}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}         


%bib
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex} % load the package


\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\def\blx@bblfile@biber{%
  \blx@secinit
  \begingroup


  \blx@bblstart
  \blx@ifsigned{\jobname}{bbl}
    {%
\LetLtxMacro{\refsectionOld}{\refsection}
\LetLtxMacro{\endsortlistOld}{\endsortlist}
\LetLtxMacro{\endrefsectionOld}{\endrefsection}
\LetLtxMacro{\sortlistOld}{\sortlist}
\def\refsection{\def\refsection{\@gobble}\refsectionOld}
\def\endsortlist{\def\endsortlist{\endsortlistOld}}
\def\endrefsection{\def\endrefsection{\endrefsectionOld}}
\def\sortlist{\def\sortlist{\@gobbletwo}\sortlistOld}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.bbl}
       {\blx@info@noline{... file '\jobname.bbl' found}}
       {\blx@info@noline{... file '\jobname.bbl' not found}%
        \typeout{No file \jobname.bbl.}}}
    {}%
  \blx@bblend
  \endgroup
  \csnumgdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}}

\makeatother


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addbibresource{\jobname-resource2.bib}
\begin{document}
This is a citation \cite{C2014}
\begin{refsection}[\jobname-resource1.bib]
\nocite{*}
\end{refsection}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

This completely disables the ability to have multiple reference sections. You should be able to hack the macros to restore themselves at the correct time if you need multiple reference sections.

Comment: +1 Cool idea. But doesn't that solution have a problem with disambiguations as well? I cannot tell whether "Author 2014" refers to "First Paper" or "Third Paper".

Comment: Mhhh, if I cite just one of the entries and `\nocite` the rest in a normal (non-modified) `authoryear` document, I get a disambiguation.

Comment: If I run the OP's MWE I do get "N. Author (2014)" instead of just "Author (2014)", that is the disambiguation I was referring to and was missing in your solution. (I was not talking about the letters added to the year for works by the same author(s) from the same year, that is where my example above gets into trouble.)

Comment: @moewe You are correct, my solution screws up disambiguation. It also seems to screw up the sort order. It appears that `\sortlist{entry}{nyt}` doesn't actually do the sorting.

Comment: @moewe now I see, I am a little slow today. I will have to look into how `biber` and `biblatex` do disambiguation.

Answer (score 1):

This solution adapted from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/WKaSUTrvAV8 worked for me.

It uses the methods of "segments", which allows to cite all references from one bibliography, and only those that are truly cited in the other. Interestingly, this still preserves the ability to cite any reference, from both bibliographies, anywhere (this is not possible with refsection environment).

Here is my MWE (from a reduction of my code, hope it works), assuming you have two .bib files, persobiblio.bib and biblio.bib:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[    
%    style=authoryear,   
    natbib=true,     
    firstinits=true,
    sorting=ydnt,
    defernumbers,
    maxnames=50
]{biblatex}

% First, personal, bibliography. Contains the keyword "own"
\addbibresource{persobiblio.bib} 

% Second, external bibliography (without "own" in keywords)
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
% cite something from biblio.bib 
\cite{key}    

% Printing external bibliography (only contains "key")
\printbibliography[segment=0,notkeyword=own,title={External Bibliography},resetnumbers]

% Printing personal bibliography (print all references inside), 
% with a prefix to possibly distinguish them from external ones
\newrefsegment 
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=own,title={Personal Publications}, prefixnumbers={{P}-},resetnumbers]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple but it has taken me quite a while to figure it out, hence I post my answer nonethless.

Change parts of your code as follows (assuming you want A2014 in your bibliography):

```
%bib
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex} % load the package
\addbibresource{\jobname-resource1.bib}
\nocite{*}
\addbibresource{\jobname-resource2.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

This is a citation \cite{C2014}

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `\nocite{*}` applies to both resources.

Comment: Yes, can confirm. At best it used to work, if ever.