# Cite all references of one (among several) bibliographic file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Background: *I'm writing a paper, in which I study a corpus of references (they are all entries matching a particular keyword on Scopus).

I have thus two `.bib` files: the one I use all the time with every papers I've ever read (`main.bib`), and the one with all extracted entries (`extracted.bib`). Of course, I don't want to merge them.*

**Question:** How to generate a bibliography with all entries of `extracted.bib` only?
Since I know how to create several bibliographies using [`bibunits`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibunits), and [how to use BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/64454); I think my real question is **how to `\nocite` all entries of one `.bib` file only?**

(Since `extracted.bib` has 100+ entries, `\nocite`-ing each entry is not an option `(-;`).

Comment: Currently there is no way to selective `\nocite` only one `.bib` file if you want to use multiple files in the same refsection. See [\nocite{*} for single bibdatasources with biblatex/biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170316/35864), [issue #228 at the `biblatex` bug tracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/228), as well as [Is it possible to add entries to the bibliography based on keyword using Biblatex/Biber and within the document code?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258888/35864)

Comment: Depending on how your set up is exactly and what specifically you are trying to do, there might be work-arounds for you, though.

Comment: @moewe `\begin{refsection}[main.bib] <whole paper> \printbibliography \end{refsection}\begin{refsection}[extracted.bib] \nocite{*} \printbibliography \end{refsection}` works (I've used a dummy databas)! Thx `(-:` ! Do you want to answer, or we flag my question as duplicate of [\nocite{*} for single bibdatasources with biblatex/biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170316/64454)?

Comment: I guess it's a duplicate as the answers in the other question explicitly mention using `refsection`s with designated files.