# nocite all entries of a biblatex entry type

Tags: biblatex, citing, bibentry

I am writing my cv and although I only want to print some of my `@unpublished` and `@inproceedings` entries in my bibliography, I do want to print all of my `@article` entries.

Is there any way in which I can `\nocite` all entries of a specific type (`@article` in this case)?

Consider that I have my entries in separate files depending on its type. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{articles.bib}
\addbibresource{talks.bib}
\addbibresource{unpublished.bib}

\begin{document}

% How do I nocite all @article entries?
\nocite{<all @article entries>}

\nocite{sometalk, someothertalk}

\nocite{someunpublished, someotherunpublished}


% This should print all articles
\printbibliography[title=Articles, type=article]

% This should print sometalk and someothertalk
\printbibliography[title=Talks, type=inproceedings]

% This should print someunpublished and someotherunpublished
\printbibliography[title=Unpublished, type=unpublished]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\nocite` only supports listing *entry keys* you want to add to your bibliography or `\nocite{*}` to allow *all* available entries from your `.bib` file(s) to be added.

There is no way to tell `\nocite` to pick only `@article`s or entries with other properties, see [\nocite{*} for single bibdatasources with biblatex/biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170316/35864), [Is it possible to add entries to the bibliography based on keyword using Biblatex/Biber and within the document code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258888/35864).

There is, however, a workaround in newer versions of Biber that allows you to clear out entries you don't want with a sourcemap. This will result in the expected output.

You will need the `starnocited` keyword that was added in `biblatex` 3.15/Biber 2.15 (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/319).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \pernottype{article}
      \step[starnocited=true, final]
      \step[entrynull]
    }
  }
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\nocite{westfahl:space,gaonkar:in}

\nocite{salam} % we don't want moraux


% This should print all articles
\printbibliography[title=@article, type=article]

% This should print salam but not moraux
\printbibliography[title=@inproceedings, type=inproceedings]

% This should print westfahl:space gaonkar:in and nothing else
\printbibliography[title=@incollection, type=incollection]

\end{document}
```

[image: Part of the generated bibliography.]

This clears out all entries that are not `@article`s that are only present because of `\nocite{*}` (i.e. entries that were not `\cite`d or `\nocite`d explicitly with their key)